# Understanding solution to first-order differential equation written in integral form, $y(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt + x + 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I have a differential equation and I'm trying to understand the solution printed in the back of the book. I will specify what part I'm struggling to understand:

**Problem statement:** Solve the following equation. $y(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt + x + 1$.

**Verbatim solution from back of the book that I'm trying to understand:**
$y(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt + x + 1 ⇒ \frac{dy}{dx} = y(x) + 1 ⇒ \frac{dy}{dx}- y = 1 ⇒ u(x) = e^{\int-1dx} = e^{-x} ⇒ \frac{d}{dx}[e^{-x}y] = e^{-x} ⇒ e^{-x}y = \int e^{-x}dx = -e^{-x} + C ⇒ y = Ce^{x} - 1.$

*But there is an implied initial condition here:* $y(0)=1.$ Therefore, $1=y(0)=Ce^{0}-1⇒C=2$, so that the solution is $y=2e^{x}-1.$ [*Try any other value of C and see that the function doesn't satisfy the original equation.*]

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is $y(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt = y(x)$, and not $y(x)-y(0)$?
2. Why is there an implied initial condition when there is no implied condition stated in the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is the direct result of the first part of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

2) You can see in the original equation, when $x=0$ the integral [vanishes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Conventions), as does $x$, leaving you the condition $y(0)=1$. This is certainly true, so this condition has to be satisfied.

Comment: Nice edits, thank you. I was being lazy.